# What is the explicit form of the formula in Predict function in R

Tags: r, regression

I fit my data.frame, g

```
`     Day  V`       
1      13  211.45
2      15  274.40
3      18  381.15
4      21  499.80
5      26  614.65
6      29  723.75
7      33  931.70
8      36  996.35
9      40 1037.40
10     43 1277.75
```

by using the following steps

```
fit <- glm(V ~ Day, data = g, family = gaussian(link = "log"))
pred <- predict(fit, type = "response")

# get Intercept from glm
intercept<-fit$coefficients[[1]]

# Get Slope from glm
slope<-fit$coefficients[[2]]
```

Now, I want to calculate the Day for a particular value of V, say V = 800.0 based on the fit. Although I know the fit coefficients, I cannot construct a formula to calculate this.

Let's assume this exponential data can be represented by a formula like

```
V=Voexp(mt)
```

where

```
 Vo is the intercept 
 m is the slope the fit
```

then, the Day for a particular V = 800.0 can be calculated by

```
 t(V) = log(V/intercept)/slope
```

I do not know what formula predict function is using to calculate predicted values based on the fit. I tried to do the following

```
new<-data.frame(V=c(800.00))
p<-predict(fit,newdata=new, type=response")
```

I get the following error

```
Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'Day' not found
```

This is because, this function is intended to calculate, V from a new Day, not the other way around.

But how can I do this using R?

Comment: I think OP just needs a little theoretical straightening out - not to use uniroot. OP, the link transforms the entire right side of the equation, so while you *could* simplify to `V = Vo * exp(m * t)`, the equation that R is fitting is `V = exp(coef[1] + coef[2] * Day)`. So `Vo = exp(coef[1])`.

Comment: Thank you 李哲源. I think I have a solution.

Comment: Gregor. Your solution is not complete. It ends without conclusion. Could you please finish it? Thank you.

Comment: Thank you 李哲源. That's what I used.

Comment: Gregor, to find out the time, the V  becomes  2xVo (V doubling time, VDT), I use V = Vo * exp(m * t) formula to fit. Then VDT is t(V=2Vo) = log(2)/m.  But in this case, the formula is V  = exp(a + m*t). How do I calculate VDT in this case?

Comment: I can write up an answer later, but you need to use `m = coef[2]` and `intercept = Vo = exp(coef[1])`. Everything else is the same.

Comment: If it might be if any use to you, I obtained a good fit to this data with the Michaelis-Menten equation "Y = (a * X) / (b + X) + Offset" using parameters a = -1.6459824177690061E+04, b = -5.4161297583662520E+02 and Offset = -1.8881145899816408E+02. The R-squared = 0.987 and RMSE = 37.87.

Comment: Gregor, from V = exp(coef[1] +coef[2)] * t), and Vo = exp(coef[1]), V = Vo * exp(coef[2] * t), which gives, log(V/Vo) = coef[2] * t, so that t(V) = log(V(exp(coef[1])) /coef[2]). But this equation gives wrong values for t for any V values, although the fit is not bad.  Since this data is expected to vary normally (Gaussian), the expected volme growth is exponential. Therefore, is it possible to define the fit formula as V = Vo*exp( m * t) instead of "family = gaussian(link = "log")", so that the fiting calculates Vo and m?  Then I can calculate the VDT and the T for any V?